# Comparar uma célula com todas as outras células da mesma coluna

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, comparação

Preciso comparar uma celular específica da planilha com todas as outras células da mesma coluna para encontrar duplicidades e tratar essa célula, algo como

`If (célula) = (todas as células da coluna) Then`

Mas não conheço suficiente de vba para conseguir montar isto.

Agradeço desde já pelas possíveis sugestões.

Answer (score 0):

Option Explicit

Private Sub ComparaCelula()

Dim iCell, iCell1, Rng      As Range

Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)  'Conta linhas com dados

For Each iCell In Rng   'Loop para cada célula

```
For Each iCell1 In Rng    'Dentro da mesma coluna
  
  If iCell = iCell1 Then    'Compara se é igual
    
    'Ação 1
    
    Else
    
    'Ação 2
    
  End If
  
Next iCell1
```

Next iCell

End Sub

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Você precisa comparar com cada outra célula individualmente, dentro de um laço `for`.

Outra alternativa interessante é fazer este cálculo com fórmulas na própria planilha, e só ler o resultado na macro (se ainda for necessário). Isso simplifica muito o projeto e é muito mais rápido.

Comment: Acredito que o cálculo com fórmulas e depois a leitura na macro seja exatamente o que eu precisava, vou testar assim que possível. Muito Obrigado!